# Can you use Java and Objective C in Expo Modules?

Tags: java, swift, react-native, kotlin, expo

I have an Expo project in which I want to re-use some existing Java and Obj-C native code.
The Expo Modules docs (https://docs.expo.dev/modules) only have examples for Kotlin and Swift. They don't even mention Java and Obj-C.

Do Expo modules not support the older languages? It seems like there must be some way to do it, right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the answer is no.

I ended up having to create [React Native Modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro) (not Expo modules) with Java and Objective-C code.

Expo still finds these modules during prebuild and they get compiled.